# Flask: redirect does not render template when redirecting from a POST

Tags: flask

I have an app cloned from the flasky app.
I have added the Google sign-in button to the login page, which sends a POST message with token details. So flasky renders a login form, but instead of the form doing POST, Google's javascript does.
I can see that the token is correctly read by my handler:

```
@auth.route('/receive_idtoken', methods=['POST'])  # gives us the idtoken. 
def receive_idtoken():
```

it then goes on to check that the user is known:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(email=idinfo['email']).first()
if user is not None:
    login_user(user,remember=True)
    flash("Congratulations, you have logged in")
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.index'))
```

The redirect causes my debugger to resume control in the handler for main.index and template renders fine. But the page never appears in the browser. The login page stays. The browser is Firefox, all on ubuntu 16.04

I guess the previous request was not terminated by the ajax post of the token?

this is how the token_id is posted:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/auth/receive_idtoken');  // to-do need to use the template for this so not to hardcode
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
```

(Newby)

Comment: Wouldn't it be the ajax request that gets redirected then? Your browser makes no request. So the ajax request receives the result of the redirect.

Comment: Oh yeah. I suppose I need the page to send a post request just like the form did. I'm using Google's example code so I will check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I now return the URL to redirect to and do  window.location.href = xhr.responseText;